# Back-to-back router configuration

Tags: networking, firewall, router

I have inherited a network where there are 2 routers ***supposedly*** configured back-to-back. They are both on the same subnet and only one serves DHCP. There is the possibility that they are not configured correctly. There are plenty of switches behind the routers so it hasn't been done for extra ports.

I have 2 questions:

1. What is back-to-back configuration?
2. What are the advantages for having this sort of configuration?

Comment: What do you mean by "*back-to-back*", given that you also say they're on the same subnet.

Comment: I guess there is a possibility that they aren't. I was told that they were. I'm trying to figure out exactly what back-to-back means and reasons why it should be that way.

Comment: The best advice I can give you is to actually look at the configuration on each of the routers and try to figure out what the previous admin meant by the term.

Answer (score 1):

This article may answer your question [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc723426.aspx). Back-to-back 
configuration in general terms is when server computers are located on either side of the perimeter network also known as the DMZ